# Why does SVG text behave so strangely with multiline text

Tags: svg, text, snap.svg

http://cjohn.design

Under the portfolio and profile section, the text only looks right on chrome desktop. On Safari mobile and desktop and chrome mobile, it adds strange line breaks.

Anyone know?

Comment: You need a [mcve] rather than having us wade through an entire site.

Comment: @RobertLongson Great article, Thanks!